# Moving only specific commits to production using git

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Recently we have been finding ourselves in situations where we want to merge our test branch with production and exclude specific commits. There have been two ways I have been going about it, one is to merge test with production and do a rebase against the merge commit (git rebase -i HEAD~1) and remove the commits that I do not want. Another would be to cherry pick the commits that we want. I am trying to avoid cherry picking all together since it seems to create a new commit on the separate branches and dirty up the working trees.

Is rebasing the merge commit a good strategy? Does anyone see anything wrong with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rebasing is basically the same thing as cherry picking. You'll get "new commits" (i.e. new commit hashes) either way. What is your motivation for merging specific commits?

Comment: at certain points we want to push to production when certain issues aren't ready to move up while other tickets are (some of these issues were too small to create feature branchs for). Sometimes its one commit that needs to be brought to production and other times its almost every commit except for a few.

Comment: There is *never* an issue too small to create a feature branch for. If you're merging individual commits into your stable branch, you're asking for trouble. For example, you're not testing that code base before considering it stable.

Comment: So right now we have dev, qa and then production and the occasional feature branch for implementations we think will take a while. Should we not have a dev and just create feature branches as needed for certain tickets?

Comment: The "merge except for a few commits" is an antipattern in itself, and discussing how to accomplish that misses the point. Why do these commits need to be excluded?

Comment: trust me, I agree.. I'd much rather merge qa and production when qa is considered stable. I do like Chris's idea of creating a feature branch for every bug fix on the site and maybe being able to merge that into qa for testing and then when ready merging that feature branch into production. This would most likely allow for an agile environment instead of scheduled code pushes to production. Currently we have a dev environment we all commit to, which then gets merged to qa and then into prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend adopting [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), rather than wrangling with complicated rebases and merges for deployment.  It supports the notion of mainline development, releases, hotfixes, and feature branches.  Following that model, you'd only deploy your release and hotfixes branches.